# Deleting a UITableViewCell causes other self sizing cells to get bigger in size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using self sizing `UITableViewCell`s and they always shrink to the smallest size they can be. This is great.

However, when I delete a cell this causes the other cells to grow in size until they're next dequeued or reloaded.

I'm using the correct `UITableView` methods for deleting the datasource and cell...

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.dataSource deleteObjectsAtIndices:[self indexSetFromIndexPaths:@[indexPath]]];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

NSArray *previousDataSourceState = [self.dataSource.objects copy];
[self.dataSource reconstructObjects];
NSArray *indexPathsToBeAdded = [self indexPathsOfObjectsFromDatasource:self.dataSource.objects notPresentInDataSource:previousDataSourceState];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToBeAdded withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Could it be a priority issue with constraints? e.g content compression resistance and content hugging?

Comment: It worked or not ??

Answer (score 0):

As suspected it was a matter of priorities conflicting with each other.

To fix the issue, content hugging priority should be higher on the views you wish to keep smaller. For me this was the case with a `UIView` that was growing unexpectedly.